# How to append some line at the end of the file only if it's not there yet?

Tags: substitute, ex-command

I'd like to edit a file in-place by appending a line, only if doesn't exist yet to make my script bullet-proof.

Normally I'd do something like:

```
cat >> ~/.bashrc <<EOF
export PATH=~/.composer/vendor/bin:\$PATH
EOF
```

It is also possible to do it via ansible (`line`+`insertafter=EOF`+`regexp`), but it's another story.

In vi/ex I could do something like:

```
ex +'$s@$@\rexport PATH=\~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH@' -cwq ~/.bashrc
```

but then how do I check if the line is already there (and thus do nothing) ideally without repeating the same line?

Or maybe there is some easier way to do it in Ex editor?

Comment: Can't you outsource it? `grep -Fq 'export PATH=~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH' ~/.bashrc || ex ...` (or `cat`, for that matter)?

Comment: I believe this could be something similar to [this approach](http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/3302/467), but opposite (when string is not there, do something).

Comment: `ex ~/.bashrc -c "if search('export PATH=\~\/.composer\/vendor\/bin:\$PATH')>0 | norm quit | endif | norm Aexport PATH=~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"`

Comment: Note that `export` is a *command*, so the rest of the line is a shell word, NOT an assignment.  Therefore unlike with a variable assignment (that doesn't use `export`), [you need double quotes or it will break on whitespace](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/25704/135943).  Also see [How to correctly add a path to PATH](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26059/135943).

Comment: I found the actual link I was looking for yesterday (although the above links are good also).  [Are quotes needed for local variable assignment?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/97569/135943)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want *bulletproof*, you probably want something a little more portable than the complicated options above.  I would stick to [POSIX features of `ex`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html) and make it stupid-simple: Just remove the line if it's there (regardless of how many times it's there), add it to the end of the file, then save and exit:

```
ex -sc 'g/^export PATH=\~\/\.composer\/vendor\/bin:\$PATH$/d
$a
export PATH=~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH
.
x' ~/.bashrc
```

I anchored the regex for added robustness, though I think it's almost impossible to *accidentally* match this regex.  (Anchored means using `^` and `$` so the regex will only match if it matches an *entire* line.)

Note that the `+cmd` syntax is not required by POSIX, nor is the common feature of allowing multiple `-c` arguments.

---

There are a multitude of other **simple** ways to do this.  For instance, add the line to the end of the file, then run the last two lines of the file through the external UNIX filter `uniq`:

```
ex -sc '$a
export PATH=~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH
.
$-,$!uniq
x' input
```

This is very very clean and simple, and is also fully POSIX-compliant.  It uses the [Escape feature of `ex`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html#tag_20_40_13_52) for external text filtering, and the [POSIX-specified shell utility `uniq`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/uniq.html)

The bottom line is, `ex` is *designed* for in-place file editing and it is by far the most portable way to accomplish that in a non-interactive fashion.  It predates even the original `vi`, actually—the name `vi` is for "visual editor", and the non-visual editor it was built upon *was* `ex`.)

---

For even greater simplicity (and to reduce it to a single line), use `printf` to send the commands to `ex`:

```
printf %s\\n '$a' 'export PATH=~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH' . '$-,$!uniq' x | ex input
```

Comment: Related: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/6269/4676

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution is to create a function to do that:

```
function! AddLine()

    let l:res = 0
    g/export PATH=\~\/.composer\/vendor\/bin:\\\$PATH/let l:res = l:res+1

    if (l:res == 0)
        normal G
        normal oexport PATH=~/.composer/vendor/bin:\$PATH
    endif

endfunction
```

First we create a local variable `l:res` which will be used to count the number of occurrences of the line.

We use the `global` command: each time the line is matched, `l:res` is incremented.

Finally if `l:res` is still 0 it means that the line doesn't appear in the file so we go to the last line thanks to `G`, and we create a new line with `o` on which we write the line to add.

**Note 1** The method I used to set the value of `l:res` is a little bit heavy and could be replaced by the one suggested by @Alex in [his answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/4946/1841) with something like:

```
let l:res = search('export PATH=\~\/.composer\/vendor\/bin:\\\$PATH')
```

**Note 2** Also to make the function more flexible you can use arguments:

```
function! AddLine(line)

    let l:line =  escape(a:line, "/~$" )

    let l:res = 0
    exe "g/" . l:line . "/let l:res = l:res+1"

    if (l:res == 0)
        normal G
        exe "normal o" . a:line
    endif

endfunction
```

- Note the trick with `escape()` to add a `\` in front of the characters which might cause a problem in the search.
- Note also that you'll still have to escape the `\` by yourself when calling the function (I didn't manage to escape `\` automatically):

  ```
  call AddLine("export PATH=~/.composer/vendor/bin:\\$PATH")
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
ex ~/.bashrc -c "if search('export PATH=\~\/.composer\/vendor\/bin:\$PATH')>0 | norm quit | endif | norm Aexport PATH=~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
```

Note that `:append` won't work inside `if endif`-block with Ex mode (see [VimDoc](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#:append)) so I have to put `norm A...` outside.

Answer (score 2):

Most of these answers seem complicated how about good old shell commands:

```
grep composer/vender ~/.bashrc || cat >> ~/.bashrc <<EOF
export PATH=~/.composer/vendor/bin:\$PATH
EOF
```

This could easily be a Bash function:

```
addBashrcPath() {
  if ! grep "$1" ~/.bashrc >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    printf 'export PATH=%s:$PATH' "$1" >> ~/.bashrc
  fi
}

addBashrcPath "~/.composer/vendor/bin"
```

**EDIT**: The exit code of grep is important and in this case it needs to be reversed use `! grep`; `grep -v` will not exit as expected in this situation. Thanks you @joeytwiddle for the tip.

Comment: I don't think `grep -v` gives you the exit code you want. But `! grep` should do it.

Comment: If that's the case then you don’t even need the `-v` just the `!`.

Comment: Exactly. You could edit your answer to make that correction.

Comment: 1. You should use `-F` so that `grep` dosn't interpret characters as regular expressions, and 2. Use `-q` instead of redirecting to `/dev/null`. See my [earlier comment on question](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4847/how-to-append-some-line-at-the-end-of-the-file-only-if-its-not-there-yet#comment7407_4847).

Comment: Good points. Curious how portable is `-q` and `-F` options? I thought the `>/dev/null` was more universal among different platforms (sun vs hp vs Mac OS X vs Ubuntu vs FreeBSD vs …)

Comment: Both `-q` and `-F` are [completely standard and portable](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html).  Unless you're on some weird, ancient, noncompliant system.

Answer (score 1):

I normally use:

```
perl -i -p0e '$_.="export PATH=~/bin:\$PATH\n" unless m!~/bin:!' ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to simplify and avoid the presence of many `\`, the line to be added will be `export PATH=mybin:PATH`.

Main strategy: substitute the "non-`mybin`" text (all  file) with text+mybin-path-definition:

```
 vim  +'s#\v%^((.|\n)(mybin:)@!)*%$#&\rexport PATH=mybin:PATH#e' -cx bashrc
```

or with *more didactic indentation*:

```
s#                                    substitute
   \v                                  very magical to redude \

   %^                                  file begin
   ((.|\n)(mybin:)@!)*                 multi-line str without "mybin:"
                                         (any char not followed by "mybin")*
   %$                                  end of file
 #                                    by
```

If we have a match:

1. `&` has the full text of `bashrc` and
2. `&` does not contain `/mybin:/`

so:

```
 #                                    by ...
   &                                   all file
   export PATH=mybin:PATH              and the new path
 #e                                   don't complain if patt not found

-cx                                   save and leave
```

**UPDATE**: Finally, we can make a vim script:

```
$ cat bashrcfix

#!/usr/bin/vim -s
:e ~/fakebashrc
:s#\v%^((.|\n)(mybin:)@!)*%$#&\rexport PATH=mybin:PATH#e
:x
```

chmod 755 and install it. Usage: `bashrcfix`

---

be careful: in `\v` mode, `=` means optional